# Can I see the out of bag error for regression tasks in the R randomForest package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm using the randomForest package in R for prediction, and want to plot the out of bag (OOB) errors to see if I have enough trees, and to tune the mtry (number of variables at each split) variable. The package seems to automatically compute the OOB errors for classification tasks, but doesn't do so for regression tasks. Does anyone know if there is a way to look at the OOB errors for regressions tasks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For regression, the random forest object reports the mean of the squared residuals (for OOB cases), although the documentation isn't as clear about this as it could be.

Comment: I was under the impression that the mse and rsq measures in the randomForest objects were computed in-sample, rather than OOB. So, I guess they are actually computed OOB then. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure it's OOB. You can always just look at the source code to verify...

Answer (score 2):

You can also look directly at the out of bag predictions:

```
data(airquality)
set.seed(131)
ozone.rf <- randomForest(Ozone ~ ., data=airquality, mtry=3,
                         importance=TRUE, na.action=na.omit)
ozone.rf$predicted
```

And then you can calculate also other measures like eg median absolute error.

Comment: Sorry for the dig up, but I don't see the OOB predictions there, only the cases that were omitted due to NA's and the predicted remaining cases.

Comment: The predictions are the out-of-bag predictions.

See the help of **randomForest**: 
`predicted 
the predicted values of the input data based on out-of-bag samples.`

I would also rather use ranger for which the outcome is much better understandable.

Here a code example for getting the OOB-Predictions of ranger: 

`ranger(Species ~ ., data = iris, probability = TRUE)$predictions`

You can also use my package "OOBCurve" to get the learning curve of the OOB-Predictions in random forest.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments the mse object is computed OOB. See page 20 in
https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Random-Forest-%5bLiaw-and-Weiner%5d.pdf
Hence, the mse object is already an estimate of the OOB mean squared error.